# Feat which allows a PC to use a Ranged weapon in 'Melee Range' without provoking Opportunity Attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

Is there a Feat of some sort which allows the use of a Ranged weapon in 'Melee Range' without provoking an Opportunity attack?

Comment: Is there a specific build/use case you have in mind? Because no such general feat exists(Except for Sling expertise, but that locks you to slings).

Comment: There build I had in mind is a Rogue using a Melee weapon in one hand and a *Hand Crossbow in the other.

Comment: come to chat :) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat we can find you something that will work :)

Comment: @Lucifer Chat is great for build advice; I highly recommend asking about it in there. :)

Answer (score 11):

There appear to be a few feats along these lines, but none are as straightforward as "You get to use a ranged weapon without provoking an opportunity attack."

The closest may be these three, which require the *Harrowing Swarm Student* feat and are from *Martial Power 2* p115-116, and are for Warlords, Rangers and Rogues, respectively:

> #### Harrowing Swarm Captain [Greater Style] (Warlords)
>
> **Benefit:** When you are attacking with a bow or a crossbow and you have proficiency with that weapon, you gain the following two benefits: You do not provoke an opportunity attack from the target of your attack. You can use a power associated with this feat as a ranged power instead of a melee power.

> #### Harrowing Swarm Scout [Greater Style] (Rangers)
>
> **Benefit:** When you are attacking with a bow or a crossbow and you have proficiency with that weapon, you gain the following two benefits: You do not provoke an opportunity attack from the target of your attack. When you use a power associated with this feat, you can use your bow or crossbow instead of a thrown weapon. If you do so, you use Dexterity instead of Strength for attack rolls and damage rolls.

> #### Harrowing Swarm Stalker [Greater Style] (Rogues)
>
> **Benefit:** When you are attacking with a bow or a crossbow and you have proficiency with that weapon, you gain the following two benefits: You do not provoke an opportunity attack from the target of your attack. You can use a power associated with this feat as a ranged power instead of a melee power and you can attack using a crossbow instead of a light blade.

---

The remainder I could find get fairly specific as to the circumstances under which you can avoid provoking OAs:

- **Opportunistic Archer**, a paragon tier feat for an 11th level elf fighter, from *Martial Power p144*: *"When you can make a melee basic attack against a target because of Combat Challenge, you can instead make a ranged basic attack with a bow against the target. The ranged basic attack does not provoke opportunity attacks."*
- **Sling Expertise** from *Heroes of the Fallen Lands* p317 and *Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdoms* p318 allows you to make a sling attack without provoking OAs (as well as increasing your attack stat).
- **Combat Casting** for the Swordmage, from *Arcane Power* p124, has this effect: *"When you use a melee swordmage attack power and hit an enemy, your ranged and area swordmage attack powers don’t provoke opportunity attacks until the end of your next turn."*
- **Defensive Throw** for the Ranger, from *Martial Power 2* p132, has a similar effect: *"Whenever you make a melee attack, your ranged attacks with thrown weapons don’t provoke opportunity attacks until the start of your next turn."*

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure about a feat, but there is Shadowdance Armor from *Seekers of the Ashen Crown* page 26, a level 5 uncommon item. Its property states *"Your area and ranged attacks don’t provoke opportunity attacks."* It is compatible with cloth or leather.